# Spark 2.1 JAVA UDAF with Constant as arguments

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create an UDAF in JAVA and pass some constant as an argument. This constant will be used as filter inside UDAF function.

```
 +------+-------+
 | sales| city  |
 +------+-------+
 |  100 | Mumbai|
 |  70  | Pune  |
 |  50  | Delhi |
 +------+-------+
```

I want get count of cities where sales greater than 50 and less than 50 for e.g . This 50 will be passed as constant argument and is dynamic.

Anyone have any suggestions on this.

Comment: You can try lit() function in org.apache.spark.sql.functions. Using this, you can pass constant values in udf or udaf.

Comment: I have tried lit but it's not working. select uf(sales,lit("50")) as count from cities;Getting the below exception.
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'lit'